# How to set url for the uploaded file in FileSystemStorage(location)

Tags: django

i want to set the correct url of my file which is provided in the location of filesystemstorage

views.py

```
 if request.method=='POST' and request.FILES.get('myfile', None):
    myfile=request.FILES['myfile']
    print(myfile.name.split('.'))
    image_name_banner = image_name +'-' + 'banner' + '.' +myfile.name.split('.')[-1]
    print(image_name_banner)
    myfile.name = image_name_banner
    fs=FileSystemStorage(location='media/events/images')
    print(fs)
    filename=fs.save(myfile.name,myfile)
    print(filename)
    print(fs.url)
    uploadedfileurl=fs.path(filename)
    u_banner=uploadedfileurl
    print(u_banner)
```

the u_banner  is printing the default url as media/filename.jpg

Comment: yes i want the whole url media\static\images\filename.jpg

Comment: as told the output which is u_banner. is just printing media\filename.jpg... which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
def upload_example(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']: 
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location='media/events/images/')
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile) 
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)  # file url
        return render(request, 'yourpagehere.html', { 
        'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url 
    }) 
    return render(request, 'yourpagehere.html')
```

`uploaded_file_url` contains the url of the uploaded file

More info about file uploads can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/)